# ROS Stream prints spurious characters to log

Tags: ros, roslaunch, logging

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I launched a node with roslaunch. The node uses ROS_*_STREAM macros to log information. The log file created by the node however shows spurious characters. Following line shows an example

^[[0m[ INFO] [1325453858.376186830]: Alasca scan: time=-0.000000, points=31, nodes=11^[[0m

Every line in the log file starts and ends with "^[[0m". Does anyone know what might cause this behavior. This happens with not just this node, but all nodes that I launch with roslaunch.

ROS: Electric, OS: Ubuntu 11.10 x86

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12497/ros-stream-prints-spurious-characters-to-log/) by [Aditya](https://answers.ros.org/users/1106/aditya/) on ROS Answers with karma: 287 on 2012-01-01

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To me they look like escape sequences for colorization.
The 0 should reset all previous color commands.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-01-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3